# Should rollbacks be included in a user's recent activity history?

Tags: feature-request, edits, recent-activity, rollbacks

Why are rollbacks not included in a user's recent activity history?

When you go to a user's profile and click on recent, why can you not see where they have rolled back posts? Isn't this just as relevant as the edits it shows?

---

#### Example:

> https://stackoverflow.com/users/383?tab=recent#sort-top
> https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/686228/list

Comment: You should make it a feature request perhaps...

Comment: This was noticed when we were looking over the recent activity on my [Wedding Cake Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686216/what-code-would-you-have-on-your-wedding-cake/686228#686228) answer. It appears that GateKiller's rollback was not recorded in his recent activity, nor was it included in Rich B's activity. Yet when I revised (not a rollback) I did get an inclusion in my activity list.

Comment: "Include rollbacks in recent history"

Comment: @jjnguy: I doubt this was overlooked, there must be some reason behind it.

Comment: @**He Who Must Not Be Named**(ha, I want a nickname too...) I see.  Yeah, if you assume they already though about it then asking why it wasn't implemented makes more sense.

Comment: **BoldTest** Not bold @**NotBold**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the rationale has to do with the fact that rollbacks don't really create anything new.  That's just a guess, though.

The other alternative is that they wanted people to be able to see the other things you've done on this site, other than your constant rollback wars.