# Include rollbacks in recent history

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, rollbacks

Yesterday I rolled back [this](https://superuser.com/revisions/41529/4) answer and, as it was my first rollback, got the "cleanup badge" and all was well in the world.

However, when I go to my "activity" tab I can't find any trace of the rollback, only the fact I got the badge. Is a rollback not an action that needs to be logged/easily findable? In my case this was rolling back some self-vandalism of a post and I wanted to keep an eye on it.

Maybe this could come under the "revisions" tab...or if it is already present and I just can't find it please say.

Comment: There is also [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4823/155320) but from July 2009 and has no "definitve" answer, apart from the idea that `rollbacks don't add anything new`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will happen in the next build, we couldn't find a reason they were consciously left off, we just didn't consider them...because, well, we didn't. They'll now be included.

Comment: Much appriciated.

Answer (score 7):

Considering that edits to posts show under the action of "revised" I'd *definitely* consider this a revision/edit, IMO, therefore rollbacks should *definitely* be there.

Additionally, it's activity of the user.  This definitely falls under the category of activity that the user performed.