# Why don't rollbacks count as activity in my network profile?

Tags: support, network-profile, recent-activity, rollbacks

If I **rollback** a post on a particular SE site, this edit counts as recent activity in that particular site. However, it looks as though such edit is **not** included in `all activity` in my network profile.

Assuming this is indeed the case, why is the edit not included?

---

Related:

- [Should rollbacks be included in a user's recent activity history?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4823/343170)
- [Include rollbacks in recent history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110936/343170)

Comment: I don't see any on your Network Profile: https://stackexchange.com/users/8447955/rodrigo-de-azevedo?tab=activity, but I do see it on someone else's NP:  https://stackoverflow.com/users/11110340/md-musfiqur-rahaman?tab=activity&sort=all - https://stackexchange.com/users/15400754/md-musfiqur-rahaman?tab=activity reviews tab:   SuggestedEditOverrideToRejected suggested edit

Comment: @Rob technically, that's a review, which is different from a rollback performed from a Q&A page. (Of course, the result is the same.)

Comment: @Glorfindel Mebe, but he's lacking the [Cleanup] badge too, a second indication that *something didn't click*; and a bronze badge is not something he could lose. --- See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4/cleanup  https://stackexchange.com/users/8447955/rodrigo-de-azevedo?tab=activity   - The newest [Cleanup] is on HSM.

Comment: Please refrain from pointless edits. Bumping your post is really frowned upon.

Comment: Also please provide examples so your claims can be verified.

Comment: I really don't like empty/useless edits just to bump. That's abuse of your privileges. Don't do it again.

Answer (score -4):

Because a rollback is not a major event, unlike upvotes and downvotes. It's not important enough to show on the network profile.

Comment: Upvotes and downvotes also don't show on the particular section of the network profile that the question author is referring to.

Comment: Oh, @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog.